# django modelform has_changed analogue for serializers

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following simple code where I update model instance using DRF serializers:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get(id = id)
serializer = MySerializer(instance, data = data)
if serializer .is_valid():
    serializer .save()
```

Now, the question is, can we check whether the data has been changed or not? Just like we do for Django Forms:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    if serializer.has_changed(): # ???
```

If we can't, then is there any more or less native way of writing my own method to check it ?